# how to check which software is licensed for programs that do not use an access key, but an email account

Tags: javascript, python

I need to discover all the software that I have authenticated on my network, but some of these are released by user (e-mail). So I wanted to know if there is any place on the computer that stores this information.

I was able to access it through the computer's registry, but there it only stores information for licenses that were authenticated using a key and not for licenses that use online authentication

Comment: Every manufacturer does this differently.  You can make educated guesses, but there is no universal rule.